# How to get user uid and name used in docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have docker image with custom user (for example tod). I want to find out information about this user without creating a container.

Base image: centos8

UPD: A little about context.
I run an unprivileged container in k8s and get the following error:
`container has runAsNonRoot and image has non-numeric user (tod), cannot verify user is non-root`

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720308/kubernetes-podsecuritypolicy-set-to-runasnonroot-container-has-runasnonroot-and) answer and cannot understand why it is not possible to get the user id from my container.

Comment: Why the specific "without creating a container" constraint?  `docker run --rm imagename id` will frequently work but technically violates this requirement.

Comment: This image is checked by k8s and it cannot find the user id.
but if you go to the container, the user has an id. Magic)

Comment: Can you add some more details to the question about what specifically you're trying to check for, in which context?  (Every process will have _some_ user ID; you can override the container's uid in both `docker run` and a Kubernetes Pod spec; it's common to configure Kubernetes to disallow processes to run as root; it's uncommon but possible for a container to start as root but then switch to an unprivileged user.)

Comment: I added context

Comment: Here is the PR that explains this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/56503 Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Matt I have a kubernetes 1.17.9 in a Rancher. This version is builded on `2020-07-15T16: 10: 45Z`. However, the error does not occur with the minikube on the same version of Kubernetes.
This pull request seems to be valid on these k8s version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try to analyze the following code:

[github code reference link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/cea1d4e20b4a7886d8ff65f34c6d4f95efcb4742/pkg/kubelet/kuberuntime/security_context_others.go#L47-L48)

```
case uid == nil && len(username) > 0:
    return fmt.Errorf("container has runAsNonRoot and image has non-numeric user (%s), cannot verify user is non-root (pod: %q, container: %s)", username, format.Pod(pod), container.Name)
```

This is the code that print the error you see. You see the error because `uid == nil` and at the same time `username != ""`.

But why username has value and uid does not? Why couldn't they both have value?

It turns out that they couldn't because UID and the username are mutually exclusive. Have a look at the description of these parameters:

[github code reference link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/3895b1e4a0f8044540365a5a0a086cba0af77340/staging/src/k8s.io/cri-api/pkg/apis/runtime/v1/api.pb.go#L5158-L5164):

```
// UID that will run the command(s). This is used as a default if no user is
// specified when creating the container. UID and the following user name
// are mutually exclusive.
Uid *Int64Value `protobuf:"bytes,5,opt,name=uid,proto3" json:"uid,omitempty"`
// User name that will run the command(s). This is used if UID is not set
// and no user is specified when creating container.
Username string `protobuf:"bytes,6,opt,name=username,proto3" json:"username,omitempty"`
```

So turns out it's not a bug. It's just how the container runtime interface standard got designed, and you can't do much about it.

---

What you could do is change the way you use [USER instruction in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user).

Instead of using username with USER instruction, create a user with a known uid and use this uid instead, like in example below:

```
RUN useradd -r -u 1001 appuser
USER 1001
```